# Sorting product collection attribute wise

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, products, product-collection, sorting

I am displaying products from collection.

There are ***different attributes assigned to different products***.

**Here is my code:**

```
    $collection =  Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection') 
  ->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left') 
  ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('IN' => array($category))) ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

 foreach ($collection as $_product) 
            { 
                 .....
            }
```

Here above `$category` is `category id.`

There are 2 attributes. consider A and B.

Now my problem is.. I want to display products with attribute 'A' first.. then products with attribute 'B' and then remaining products will be displayed.
I have tried.

```
$collection->addAttributeToSort('A', 'DESC');
```

But it is not working.

Can anyone help me?

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: you have tried with  ->addAttributeToSort('A', 'DESC')->->addAttributeToSort('A', 'ASC);

Comment: but there are no changes after using it.

Comment: checking and get back to you sortly